# return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-forms

I know before run the server i must be makemigrations but i can't i don't know so much python and django i can't migrate or makemigrations or runserver i tried specified for main app but still give me same error i write this 2 times nothing changed i try to make a price tracker for myself when i try makemigrations or runserver give me this error ;

```
 File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: main_app_item.status

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\Desktop\Fiyat Takip\FiyatTakip\manage.py", line 21, in <module>    
    main()
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\Desktop\Fiyat Takip\FiyatTakip\manage.py", line 17, in main        
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 387, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 403, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\Desktop\Fiyat Takip\FiyatTakip\FiyatTakip\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    from main_app.views import search
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\Desktop\Fiyat Takip\FiyatTakip\main_app\views.py", line 56, in <module>
    search_price()
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\Desktop\Fiyat Takip\FiyatTakip\main_app\views.py", line 34, in search_price
    for element in Item.objects.all():
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 274, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 55, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1142, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)   
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\KADAK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 383, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: main_app_item.status
```

so here my views.py ;

```
@login_required
def search(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        item_url = request.POST.get("searchbox")
        maximum_price = int(request.POST.get("max_price"))
        if item_url != "" and maximum_price != "":
            user = request.user
            item_model = Item(user=user, url = item_url, max_price = maximum_price)
            item_model.save()
            return redirect('search')

    return render(request, 'main_app/search.html')




def search_price():
    max_price = 170
    hdr= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.109 Safari/537.36 OPR/84.0.4316.50'}
    
    for element in Item.objects.all():
        if element.status == False:
            user = element.user
            user_email = user.email
            item_url = element.url
            max_price = element.max_price

            url = requests.get(str(item_url), headers=hdr)

            soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')
            price_span= soup.find('span', class_="price-current__amount").text[:3].split(',')
            price =int("".join(price_span))
            
            if price <= max_price:
                subject = 'Ürününüz İndirime GİRDİ!!!'
                message = f"Merhaba {user.username}, takip ettiğiniz ürün{item_url}, ayarladığınız fiyata geldi {price}"
                email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                recipient_list = [user_email]
                send_mail(subject,message,email_from,recipient_list)
                element.status = True
                element.save()

search_price()
```

and this is my model.py ;

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=700)
    max_price = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Did you use `makemigrations` and `migrate` in your project after adding `status` field to your Item model? the error is saying that this column does not exist in `Item` table. Please make sure that your models and your tables are synchronized.

Comment: Yes i try for this after add status i try makemigrations but give me this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please comment out or remove `search_price()` and try again for creating your migration files. Because you call this function on your module and since Django is instantiating this module, it'll always go through this function and since there isn't any status column yet, it can not create your migration file because it is failing in that module.

Change this part:

```
def search_price():
    max_price = 170
    hdr= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.109 Safari/537.36 OPR/84.0.4316.50'}
    
    for element in Item.objects.all():
        if element.status == False:
            user = element.user
            user_email = user.email
            item_url = element.url
            max_price = element.max_price

            url = requests.get(str(item_url), headers=hdr)

            soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')
            price_span= soup.find('span', class_="price-current__amount").text[:3].split(',')
            price =int("".join(price_span))
            
            if price <= max_price:
                subject = 'Ürününüz İndirime GİRDİ!!!'
                message = f"Merhaba {user.username}, takip ettiğiniz ürün{item_url}, ayarladığınız fiyata geldi {price}"
                email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                recipient_list = [user_email]
                send_mail(subject,message,email_from,recipient_list)
                element.status = True
                element.save()

search_price()
```

to:

```
def search_price():
    max_price = 170
    hdr= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.109 Safari/537.36 OPR/84.0.4316.50'}
    
    for element in Item.objects.all():
        if element.status == False:
            user = element.user
            user_email = user.email
            item_url = element.url
            max_price = element.max_price

            url = requests.get(str(item_url), headers=hdr)

            soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')
            price_span= soup.find('span', class_="price-current__amount").text[:3].split(',')
            price =int("".join(price_span))
            
            if price <= max_price:
                subject = 'Ürününüz İndirime GİRDİ!!!'
                message = f"Merhaba {user.username}, takip ettiğiniz ürün{item_url}, ayarladığınız fiyata geldi {price}"
                email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                recipient_list = [user_email]
                send_mail(subject,message,email_from,recipient_list)
                element.status = True
                element.save()

# search_price()  --> here you are calling this function which is the
# main reason of your error. So this line should be removed.
```

Comment: i tried but still same give me same error i don't know why

Comment: I edited my answer. Could you check it again and see if that solves your problem??

Comment: yes it's solved my problem thank you so much